# How to adjust the top of an image and an input in the same line?

Tags: html, css

I have one `<input>` and one `<img>`, Now I need to set the top of them in the one line (I want to have both of them `margin-top:20px` from the parent) ... [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeak4rgo/)

HTML:

```
<div> <lable>Captcha</lable> <input /> <img src="an image url"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
div{border: 1px solid;}
input{margin:20px;}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: do display:inline-block and vertical-align:top to both of them.

Comment: @RezaMansouri still it does not work.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/yeak4rgo/1/

Comment: @RezaMansouri you warped `<img>` in the another `<div>` and I did not want it, anyway thanks for your try ... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label> not <lable> too
```

> The vertical-align property sets the vertical alignment of an element.
>
> inline-block  Displays an element as an inline-level block container.
>   The inside of this block is formatted as block-level box, and the
>   element itself is formatted as an inline-level box

HTML

```
<div> <label>Captcha</label> <input /> <img src="an image url"> </div>
```

CSS

```
div {border: 1px solid; padding:10px;}

input{margin:20px; vertical-align:top;}

img {margin:20px; vertical-align:top;}

label { margin: 20px 0 0 0; display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 upvote for you. actually the answer of my question is `vertical-align:top;top;` for `img`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
div{border: 1px solid;}
input{margin:20px;}
img,input,label{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block !important;
}


    <div class="tbl">
    <lable>Captcha</lable>
    <input />
    <img height="30" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRkLnpEt_2JFEnWTE1wTqUA64mJZd6stVBLz1CRQMEW4mSuOl5mmA">
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks buddy, hower the top of img and input are not exactly in the same line (in your fiddle), but +1 upvote for you.

Answer (score 0):

try with float left:

```
<div> <lable style="float:left">Captcha</lable> <input style="float:left;" /> <img src="an image url"> </div>
```